# Flask + React: Loading huge data in Flask api and displaying it in React app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, lazy-loading

I am new to flask and react. I am trying to load a large amount of data in python using pandas. Once loaded, I want to send it to the front-end (which is in React) and display it. Since the data is very large, I am trying to send the data to the client using lazy loading.

**BACKEND**

```
@app.route("/lazy/")
def lazy():
    return Response(lazy_load())


def lazy_load():
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 1000):
        yield df.iloc[i: i + 1000, :].to_json()
```

**FRONTEND**

```
class App extends React.Component {

  mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", 'request data')
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>    
    </div>
    );

  }
}
```

As you can see, my api is sending chunks of 1000 rows in the form of json.
Now I want to display these chunks and append the new rows to the existing table so that It seems like it's lazy loading and doesn't slow down the browser.

Comment: You need to create one state variable & store data inside that variable & in jsx loop through that data

Comment: When you load 1000 at the time and but keep rendering all (including the ones that are not showing on screen) you'll end up with a crashing app. Maybe have a look at [this package](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or look for alternatives for large lists. You can make paged requests and store them in state then you can still show only that page but it feels like the user can scroll through all of them.

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI I dont want to send data from api to frontend in one go as it would crash the server. The data may be in millions, which is why I want to load the data on runtime as we scroll down.

Comment: @HMR I agree with you. My intention is to load the data on the go as the user scrolls down. I would prefer infinite scroll rather than pagination. I will check that link out, thanks!